# Laravel append to every model in collection model

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I am developing an api. I have a function that returns all models in database. I wan't to append to every model of that collection the related model.

```
public function index()
    {
        if(auth()->user()->hasPermission('read-company_requests')) {
            $createCompanyRequestments = CreateCompanyRequest::orderBy('status')->get();
        } elseif(auth()->user()->hasPermission('read-company_request')) {
            $createCompanyRequestments = auth()->user()->companyCreateRequestment()->orderBy('status')->get();
        } else {abort(403);}

        return $createCompanyRequestments->toJson();
    }
```

So basicly every `CreateCompanyRequest::orderBy('status')->get();` should have the related model `company` in the response. How can I do this?

Comment: Im a little confused. A Model in laravel MVC is usually a database model. If you want the company model, you can just `use App\company` and then `company::anyPublicStaticFunctionWithinThatModel();`

Comment: Yes. Thats true. But I want that every model in `$createCompanyRequestments` has the related `company` model.

Comment: But what model? `CreateCompanyRequest::orderBy('status')->get();` just gives you a `collection();` or an array if you will. If you want every item within that collection, you can do `foreach ($createCompanyRequestments as $item) { dd($item); }`.

Comment: Thats the point i've been stuck. I want to select every related model. I've heard that you can use joins, but I am not that experienced with sql. I know that the related model isn't in that collection, but I want to include them, but i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) like so:

```
CreateCompanyRequest::orderBy('status')->with('company')->get()
```